# Javascript is not working when used with UpdatePanel

Tags: javascript, updatepanel, registerstartupscript, pagerequestmanager

I placed the following code in two pages.

1. A simple aspx page, there it worked well.
2. A page contains a lot of controls and Update Panels. There the code
   did not work. So I experimented with PageRequestManager.

Anybody know what should I do to execute the same in context of Case **2**.

```
StringBuilder jScript = new StringBuilder();

jScript.Append("<script type='text/javascript'>");
jScript.Append("Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(AlertMe);");
jScript.Append("function AlertMe() {");
jScript.Append("    alert('Hi Hoo')");
jScript.Append("}");
jScript.Append("AlertMe();");
jScript.Append("</script>");

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(string), "save_as", jScript.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am not sure i understand you right, but may be you are searching for function

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript()

because Page.ClientScript is obsolete now, and it's function "RegisterStartupScript" does not work with update panels async postbacks.